# Deserialize YAML map of POJOs with Jackson where Map keys are an object field

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, yaml

Given class:

```
@Data
class Widget {
  String name;
  int price;
}
```

And the following yaml file:

```
Widget1:
  price: 5
Widget2:
  price: 6
Widget3:
  price: 7
```

Using Jackson I want to deserialize this into a `Map<String, Widget>` where the widget name field is set to the corresponding map key.  The following snippet works but has the downside of preventing use of immutable object types such as lombok `@Value`.  Another inelegant solution I considered was creating a separate immutable `WidgetWithName` class that is constructed after jackson deserialization.  If someone can propose a better approach, that would be of interest.

```
Map<String, Widget> getWidgets(String yaml) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
    MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Widget.class);

    map = mapper.readValue(yaml, mapType);
    map.forEach((k, v) -> v.setName(k); // so much for immutability
    return map
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jackson will not help you because it is a generalization over YAML and JSON (and XML or so I heard) and therefore provides *less* functionality than directly using SnakeYAML.

With SnakeYAML, you *could* theoretically implement this with custom constructors, but it would need a lot of knowledge about the deserialization process because YAML is not designed to merge nodes on different levels into one value.

Frankly, having a separate class is by far the simplest and best maintainable solution. A separate class named `WidgetBuilder`, with only the `price` field and a function `Widget finish(String name)` would allow you to

```java
return map.entrySet().stream().map((k, v) -> v.finish(k)).collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Widget::getName, Function.identity()));
```

which seems elegant enough. (You can collect to a list instead if you don't need the map anymore.)